# Logic Inside Getters / Setters - What's The Best Practice?

Tags: java, accessor, mutators

I have a coworker who keeps adding logic inside of our getters / setters. This seems like it's objective from all similar questions I've seen on the topic and doesn't have a clean cut answer.

I think my coworker was trying to put this logic here so it would not be repeated in the code. He could have created a separate method to keep with the DRY principle but to him putting it in the getters / setters was the best place. 
For starters we use the library Lombok to cut down on boilerplate code so it'll auto-generate these for us. There's a few though where it was decided to define them explicitly instead of having Lombok generate them so logic could be added to them. The problem I feel is unless you step into those methods (which who really steps into getters/setters when debugging???) you don't understand there's additional things occurring in those methods so it's misleading and it also breaks single responsibility.

I'm trying to understand though what's the best practice? Below I've provided some simple examples to demonstrate.

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyKeyClass key;

    public MyKeyClass  getKey {
        //I feel like this if condition should not be here, method also
        //doing more than one thing. It's setting and getting
        if(key == null) {  
            key = new MyKeyClass();
        }
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(MyKeyClass key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    private SomeOtherClass someOtherClass;

    public SomeOtherClass getSomeOtherClass() {
        return this.someOtherClass;
    }

    public void setSomeOtherClass(SomeOtherClass someOtherClass) {
        this.someOtherClass= someOtherClass;
        //Other logic that is being set, but for the key class
        //I don't think this belongs either and should be done elsewhere
        this.key.setKey(someOtherClass.getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why defer initialization of `key` anyway? To a degree, using property methods does allow encapsulation of logic in them, but discipline requires that the logic directly pertain to accessing or mutating the property. The logic you show does that, albeit unnecessarily. Also, you don't show a mutator method. Finally, that `null` check and the implicit presence of a mutator hint at potential concurrency concerns.

Comment: I added the additional missing setters/getters. Since we use Lombok which will generate them for us with some simple annotations on the class, I had forgotten to add them into this example. I am planning to refactor this code to have the methods be pure getters/setters, just wanted additional feedback before I do so. @LewBloch are you able to elaborate further about potential concurrency concerns?